# What phone would be most private and what aspects to consider?

Tags: privacy, phone, smartphone, gsm

I want to change my phone and I would not use it for anything than calling and messaging.

I would be happy to have phone the most private friendly and secure against any type of information withdraw from it.

What kind of attacks should I consider?

Why I am considering this question as information security? Because the calls and text messages or even more, all the actions done at smartphone give some output that gives indeed, information about our locations, preferences, life, relations and so on.

And me as a paranoid, sceptic person want to minimize possible knowledge about this aspects of my life. I am aware that I would not quit this at all unless I decide to turn off phone by taking away the energy from it. But I would like to try minimize risk and possibilities while using it everyday.

So I would prefer to not have GPS localizator, also the system is useless for me. Especially Android. From the other hand I think that there is no possible defend against GSM localisation.

Anyway, which kind of phone are you suggesting me to be interested in?

Some informations I got is that old Nokia 3310 was so primitive that it offers high privacy.
Also Blackberry was the privacy friendly phone, right? Any model especially? What about BlackPhone ? This is privacy focus, but lets be clear where is the system there is possibility to hack the system.

Comment: This one (cryptophone): http://www.cryptophone.de .

Comment: An original Nokia 3310 also does not support modern mobile standards -  meaning all traffic to the tower is not encrypted at all and can be easily snooped on by anyone within range.

Comment: @Overmind Isn't cryptophone extremely expensive? It's several thousand dollars for a pair of units and I don't see that it provides much more than, say, Copperhead (yes I know Copperhead is not designed for privacy, but security).

Comment: Pricing is another problem entirely. If you really want phone security it's either that or using your own OS installed in them.

Answer (score 2):

- Product advices are off-topic on Stack Exchange.
- Also, hard to say anything while your threat model is unclear. Without defining a threat model, you'll most likely end up with countermeasures which are both unsufficient and unnecessarily complex at the same time.
- Also, proper security isn't a product money can buy, it's a result of a continuous effort and discipline. The most secure phone out there won't help you much, if you, say, enter a PIN code right in front of a surveillance camera and then leave your phone there unattended.
- Without a threat model, you will either skip things important for your privacy, or will try to follow an overly complex and cumbersome policy (and will get bored by that), or both.
- Assuming a threat of wiretapping possibly being carried out by your mobile operator (or police, FBI, KGB, etc.) is out of scope of the question, if you're going to use your phone only for calling and messaging, then pick a device which supports calling and messaging, and as little of anything else as possible (so not a smartphone). If it can do anything else, do not enable or use that. This helps to reduce the attack surface.
- Assuming you're not going to put in the effort I've mentioned above, better prefer a somewhat well-known manufacturer to lower the probability of being affected by stupid vulnerabilities caused by ignorance and/or carelessness of a vendor. Don't choose an outdated model, replace and update the phone quite often.
- Make sure the phone (not *only* your SIM card, but the device itself) could be protected with a PIN code, and it allows only for a reasonable amount of invalid unlock attempts per day. Choose a PIN code longer than 4.
- Note that I'm not saying such devices even exist and are available/affordable in your region. If there isn't any, the only option you're left with is not to *avoid* but to face and *manage* your risks and threats.
- Keep less data on the phone, erase it from time to time. A portable device gets stolen, gets lost, gets damaged, so it's not something you can store sensible and important data on anyway.